# Error 500 When Deploy Project to an online webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I try to publish the project to FileZilla, I get HTTP error 500 on the website. What I do is, I publish the project from Visual Studio, I publish it to a folder, and then connect to FileZilla. I then copy the publish folder in the domain name map.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/whKNJ.jpg

https://imgur.com/a/pQZ4b1V

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error is like solving a mystery. You don’t know what exactly happened or why it happened all you know is that something’s wrong and you need to fix it.

Only solution is to build error log for getting the error information by adding the following event to Global.asax.cs

```
      void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            string err = "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
                              ". Error Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString();

            string filepath = context.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Log/");  //Text File Path
filepath = filepath + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt";   //Text File Name
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))  
            {  
                File.Create(filepath).Dispose();  
            }  
             using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))  
            {  
                sw.WriteLine(err);  
                sw.Flush();  
                sw.Close();  
            }        
        }
```

Comment: Should I just copy paste that code?, How do I log the error? And where can I see the error message?

Comment: @Mannan Bahelim.Is it a good  way to write the code on production?

Comment: Its best practice to write log to handle uncaught exception

Comment: @MannanBahelim I do not have this file :Global.asax.cs, where can I find it